# Spline graph with xAxis dateTime the line starts extremeleft/origin overlapping colorband on yAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a spline graph with xAxis DateTime the line starts from the origin overlapping on the color band
I have on the yAxis.
How to force the plotline as well as the xAxis labels to start after the color band ends on the yAxis.

[Current Behavior Where line and label overlap on the color band in y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pxVG.png)

[Expected Behavior without overlap on the color band](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNlE9.png)

Please find the jsfibble link
https://jsfiddle.net/s9qwj1h3/

Thanks in advance

````
        chart: {
            height: 250
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            align: "center",
            layout: "horizontal",
            verticalAlign: "bottom",
            alignColumns: false,
            itemDistance: 10,
            symbolHeight: 12,
            symbolWidth: 12,
            itemStyle: {
                fontSize: "11px !important"
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                millisecond: '%b-%d-%Y',
                second: '%b-%d-%Y',
                minute: '%b-%d-%Y',
                hour: '%b-%d-%Y',
                day: '%b-%d-%Y',
                week: '%b-%d-%Y',
                month: '%b-%d-%Y',
                year: '%Y'
            },
            min: null,
            max: null,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: "10px !important",
                    color: "#000"
                }
            },
            gridLineColor: "transparent",
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: "transparent",
            tickLength: 0,
            style: {
                fontSize: "10px !important",
                color: "#000"
            }
        },
        yAxis: [
            {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                width: 20,
                tickInterval: 20,
                plotBands: [
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(204,0,0)',
                        from: 0,
                        to: 30.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(226,113,113)',
                        from: 31,
                        to: 44.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(247,209,34)',
                        from: 45,
                        to: 54.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(136,207,136)',
                        from: 55,
                        to: 68.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(68,180,68)',
                        from: 69,
                        to: 87.99,
                        zIndex: 3
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgb(0,153,0)',
                        from: 88,
                        to: 100,
                        zIndex: 3
                    }
                ],
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                    x: -7,
                    y: 3,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                linkedTo: 0,
                gridLineColor: 'white',
                lineColor: "transparent",
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        ],
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter() {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    inactive: {
                        opacity: 1
                    }
                },
                enableMouseTracking: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                threshold: 0, // let zero values have some height
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                minPointLength: 10,
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: false,
            shared: false,
            followPointer: false,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.point.tooltip;
            }
        },
        series: [
        {
                    "color": "rgb(0,187,221)",
                    "data": [
                    {"x":1601490600000,"y":25},
                    {"x":1601577000000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1601663400000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1601749800000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1601836200000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1601922600000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1602009000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1602095400000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1602181800000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1602268200000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1602354600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1602441000000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1602527400000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1602613800000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1602700200000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1602786600000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1602873000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1602959400000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1603045800000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1603132200000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1603218600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1603305000000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1603391400000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1603477800000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1603564200000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1603650600000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1603737000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1603823400000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1603909800000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1603996200000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1604169000000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1604255400000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1604341800000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1604428200000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1604514600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1604601000000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1604687400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1604773800000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1604860200000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1604946600000,"y":44},
                    { "x":1605033000000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1605119400000,"y":34},
                    { "x":1605205800000,"y":10},
                    { "x":1605292200000,"y":12},
                    { "x":1605378600000,"y":25},
                    { "x":1605465000000,"y":28},
                    { "x":1605551400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1605637800000,"y":22},
                    { "x":1605724200000,"y":24},
                    { "x":1605810600000,"y":44}
                 ],
                    "name": 'ABC',
                    "type": 'spline'
                },
                {
                    "color": "rgb(154,2,42)",
                    "data": [
                    {"x":1601490600000,"y":50},
                    {"x":1601577000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1601663400000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1601749800000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1601836200000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1601922600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1602009000000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1602095400000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1602181800000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1602268200000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1602354600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1602441000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1602527400000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1602613800000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1602700200000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1602786600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1602873000000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1602959400000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1603045800000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1603132200000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1603218600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1603305000000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1603391400000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1603477800000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1603564200000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1603650600000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1603737000000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1603823400000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1603909800000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1603996200000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1604169000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1604255400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1604341800000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1604428200000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1604514600000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1604601000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1604687400000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1604773800000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1604860200000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1604946600000,"y":85},
                    { "x":1605033000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1605119400000,"y":30},
                    { "x":1605205800000,"y":40},
                    { "x":1605292200000,"y":42},
                    { "x":1605378600000,"y":86},
                    { "x":1605465000000,"y":50},
                    { "x":1605551400000,"y":60},
                    { "x":1605637800000,"y":75},
                    { "x":1605724200000,"y":80},
                    { "x":1605810600000,"y":85}
                    ],
                    "name": 'XYZ',
                    "type": 'spline'
                }
        ]
    });```
````

Comment: Have you tried to set `startOnTick: true` to x-axis?

Comment: and maybe `showFirstLabel: false` could also help

Answer (score 0):

You can define the yAxis.width as a negative and set the same positive value as `yAxis.offset` to move the yAxis.

```
    yAxis: [
        {
            max: 100,
            width: -50,
            offset: 50,
            tickInterval: 20,
            ...
         }
    ]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/59n2sv8c/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.offset

Comment: @ Sebastian Wędzel thank you very much for taking the time to respond with an answer.                                              note:- sorry for the delayed response will try this approach and update the comments.